# React handleChange error with two components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want call event handleChange from a second Component

Principal component:

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({ step: 1, saleDate: new Date(), customer: '' });

  function nextStep() {
    const { step } = state;
    setState({
      step: step + 1
    });
  };

  function prevStep() {
    const { step } = state;
    setState({
      step: step - 1
    });
  };

  function handleChange(e) {
    setState(e.target.value);
  };


  const { step } = state;

  switch (step) {
    case 1:
      return <SaleStepDate
        nextStep={nextStep}
        handleChange={handleChange}
        values={state} />
  }
}
```

and second component, here is the error

```
const SaleStepDate = (props) => {

  function continueStep(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.nextStep();
  };

  const { values, handleChange } = props;

  return (
      <TextField
         placeholder="Nombre cliente"
         label="Cliente"
         name="customer"
         margin="normal"
         fullWidth="true"
         onChange={handleChange('customer')}
       />
  )
}
```

the error is in the second component in the textField event onChange={handleChange('customer')}

TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

please HELP

Comment: What is the error in console?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Maybe because of switch case in you parent component you are getting this error(if handleChange is not passed to every case component). Can you share you running code snippet in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not execute `handleChange` function when assigning to `onChange`.

Doing this `onChange={handleChange('customer')}` will first call `handleChange` function with `customer` as argument, which is why you are getting `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` as error.

Not sure what is the need for `customer` value, but if you just want to call `handleChange` with `event`, you can change the code to this:

```
<TextField
         placeholder="Nombre cliente"
         label="Cliente"
         name="customer"
         margin="normal"
         fullWidth="true"
         onChange={handleChange} //here
       />
```

Edit: Also if you want to pass `customer` use arrow function:

```
onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'customer')}
```

State Updater in `useState` do not update the whole object by default, **Updating a state variable always replaces it instead of merging it.**

```
 function handleChange(e) {
    const customer = e.target.value;
    setState(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        customer
      };
    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks! the error disappeared, but when I type on the input filed, the page becomes in a blank page.

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Few issues about your code,

First, because you are storing multiple keys at one `state` obj, by doing something like -

---

```
 setState({
  step: step + 1
});
```

---

you are delete all other content at this object. Spread rest data

---

```
setState({
  ...state,
  step: step + 1
});
```

---

As it comes to `handleChange`, for my opinion it suppose to look something like that

---

```
 function handleChange(e) {
   const { name, value } = e.target
   setState(...state, [name]: value);
 };
```

---

and can be called like

---

```
  onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
```

---

`name` will be name attribute of the HTML element, `value` the content inside the input